# Building a DSL in JavaScript similar to a Ruby DSL

Tags: javascript, dsl

I am wanting to venture more into JavaScript wanted to see if I could create a Domain Specific Language that was similar to that of something I could make in Ruby using `instance_eval` and `block_given?`. I mostly don't know what terms to search and when I search DSL I usually get some hugely meta stuff I'm not familiar with. I originally got real lucky with my Ruby search and found a good blog that helped me out. My examples in Ruby are:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'phil_dsl/version'

module PhilDsl
  class Error < StandardError; end

  # The DSL Class.
  class Pipeline
    def initialize(&block)
      if block_given? # rubocop:disable Style/GuardClause
        if block.arity == 1
          yield self
        else
          instance_eval(&block)
        end
      end
    end

    def pipeline(&block)
      if block_given? # rubocop:disable Style/GuardClause
        if block.arity == 1
          yield self
        else
          instance_eval(&block)
        end
      end
    end

    def print_stuff(name = 'bob', &block)
      puts name.to_s

      if block_given? # rubocop:disable Style/GuardClause
        if block.arity == 1
          yield self
        else
          instance_eval(&block)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then the actual usage of the DSL, once installed

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'phil_dsl'

PhilDsl::Pipeline.new.pipeline do
  print_stuff('hello') do
    print_stuff
  end
end
```

Looking at MochaJS is what I want to emulate, but I'm not sure where to start or go for figuring out how to do DSL creation similar to what I can do in Ruby.

My Ruby DSL full example: https://github.com/FilBot3/phil_dsl

Comment: This page -- [Easy Forth](https://skilldrick.github.io/easyforth/) -- implements one of my favorite languages in JavaScript -- favorite because it is so simple to implement (it used to be a rite of passage, and used to be some of the first code used to boot up a new processors.)  But it is also a high level language because it easily implements DSL's.  If you go through this tutorial, you'll see a DSL controlling a small snake game, a command-line interface, and more. View the source of the web page, and you'll see that is modularly implemented in ~9 JavaScript files, easy for you to DSL mod.

Comment: If you choose not to use Forth (as a VM / Virtual Machine, like JVM, or Microsoft's .NET Framework foundation, was MSIL, now CIL), then it still might give you a few ideas, especially how to have the DSL actually accessible by the user, if not for customers, fun for developers (and possibly for a faster development cycle).  I keep thinking of implementing a graphical language for this, where I can take SVG shapes and transfer different dimensions of them, using beziers or other splines / lines -- for fun.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as pretty in JS because you always need the `this` keyword, but the core part of a DSL is that `instance_exec` functionality, which is very easy to do in JS using `bind`, `apply`, or arrow functions.

Rather than use a class (which doesn't support arrow functions) I'll build a new scope using an IIFE:

```
MyDsl = (function(){
  return this;
}).apply({});
```

Then I'll add a single-function DSL:

```
MyDsl = (function(){
  this.print_stuff = (arg, callback) => {
    console.log(arg);
    callback && callback.apply(this);
  };
  return this;
}).apply({});
```

Since I define `print_stuff` as an arrow function I *guarantee* that inside of it, `this` will always refer to `MyDsl`.

I can then use the DSL like so:

```
MyDsl.print_stuff("foo", function() {
  this.print_stuff("bar");
});
```

Note that we *cannot* use an error function here, because then the `.apply(this)` would be ignored.